# Aes Encryption Galois/Counter Mode trying to login sever side getting invalid credential issue ,

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, aes, pointycastle

Here below the code of dart Aes encryption logic

```
  static String encryptAESGCM(String plaintext, String key) {
    try {
      final keyBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(key));
      // SecureRandom secureRandom = getSecureRandom();
      // Uint8List data = secureRandom.nextBytes(12);
        Uint8List data = generateSecureRandomData(12);
      // Uint8List data = generateNonSecureRandomData(12);
      final cipher = GCMBlockCipher(AESEngine());
      final params = AEADParameters(KeyParameter(keyBytes), 128, data, Uint8List(0));
      cipher.init(true, params); // Initialize for encryption

      final plaintextBytes = utf8.encode(plaintext);
      final ciphertextBytes = cipher.process(Uint8List.fromList(plaintextBytes)); // Process all data at once

      return base64.encode(ciphertextBytes); // Base64 encode for transmission
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle encryption errors gracefully
      print("Encryption error: $error");
      return ""; // Or return a suitable error message
    }
  }
```

```
static Uint8List generateSecureRandomData(size) {
    return Uint8List.fromList(List<int>.generate(size, (_) => Random.secure().nextInt(256))); // cryptographically secure
  }
```

here in this code i am trying to pass my username & password plain text and return it to an encrypted one
but when i use those encrypted text on my api call it shows invalid credential may be my encryption logic is not correct
here below i am pasting my server side C# code

```
public string UserNamePasswordEncryption(stringplaintext)
{
  var key = _configuration.GetSection("keypath").GetValue<string>("key");
  using var aes = new AesCcm(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
  var nonce = new byte[AesGcm.NonceByteSizes.MaxSize];
  RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(nonce);
  var plaintextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plaintext);
  var ciphertextBytes = new byte[plaintextBytes.Length];
  var tag = new byte[AesGcm.TagByteSizes.MaxSize];
  aes.Encrypt(nonce, plaintextBytes, ciphertextBytes, tag);
  return new AesGcmCiphertext(nonce, tag, ciphertextBytes).ToString();
}
```

i don't know my dart is the alternative code for this C# one

Comment: The C# code seems to use CCM: `var aes = new AesCcm(...` and not GCM!

Comment: Also, I know the `AesCcm` and `AesGcm` class, but not `AesGcmCiphertext`. Post a link to the documentation or if it is a user-defined class the code. Generally: Post the **complete** code needed for a repro, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Topaco ok will do that

Comment: @Topaco  this C# code is on server side they told me there code works fine they have done both encryption & decryption code on there side , they said the issue is on the dart code

Comment: I did not claim that the C# code does not work, but that it uses CCM, while your Dart implementation uses GCM.

Comment: i don't know how to post AesGcmCiphertext code here , can i post "AesGcmCiphertext"
code on the question itself is it ok

Comment: @Topaco i have edit the question with remaining code can you check that please

Comment: @Topaco "I did not claim that the C# code does not work, but that it uses CCM, while your Dart implementation uses GCM". so can i change it to CCM mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both codes differ in the following points:

- The C# code uses CCM as mode of operation, the Dart code GCM.
- In the C# code, the concatenation of nonce, ciphertext and tag is returned as result, in the Dart code only the concatenation of ciphertext and tag (the nonce is lost).

So that both implementations are compatible and since the C# code is the reference code, the Dart code must be adapted accordingly, e.g:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:pointycastle/api.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/block/aes.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/block/modes/ccm.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/random/fortuna_random.dart';

...

final keyBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(key));
final nonce = getSecureRandom().nextBytes(12);
final plaintextBytes = utf8.encode(plaintext);
final cipher = CCMBlockCipher(AESEngine()) // apply CCM
    ..init(true, AEADParameters(KeyParameter(keyBytes), 128, nonce, Uint8List(0)));
final ciphertextBytes = cipher.process(Uint8List.fromList(plaintextBytes)); // returns ciphertext | tag
return base64.encode(nonce + ciphertextBytes); // create nonce | ciphertext | tag

...

SecureRandom getSecureRandom() {
    List<int> seed = List<int>.generate(32, (_) => Random.secure().nextInt(256));
    return FortunaRandom()..seed(KeyParameter(Uint8List.fromList(seed)));
}
```

Notes:

- About the C# code: In the C# code, CCM is used for encryption, but sometimes GCM classes are applied. This is a bad style as it is misleading (as it happened to you). Instead, the corresponding CCM classes should be used (or renamed in the case of user-defined classes) and if the constants differ (e.g. `AesGcm.NonceByteSizes.MaxSize` = 12 and `AesCcm.NonceByteSizes.MaxSize` = 13), these should be defined explicitly.
- Regarding the CSPRNG used: With the [`SecureRandom`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pointycastle/latest/api/SecureRandom-class.html) class, PointyCastle provides a CSPRNG for which there are implementations for various algorithms, e.g. the [*Fortuna*](https://www.schneier.com/academic/fortuna/) algorithm, which is implemented in the [`FortunaRandom`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pointycastle/latest/impl.secure_random.fortuna_random/FortunaRandom-class.html) class. Since you are already using PointyCastle anyway because of the encryption (so this does not mean an additional dependency), the CSPRNG of PointyCastle can also be used. This is better documented and therefore more transparent than the poorly specified [`Random.secure()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.4/dart-math/Random/Random.secure.html) (which is usually only applied as entropy source to generate the seed when using `SecureRandom`/`FortunaRandom`).
- About the key: In general, a UTF-8 encoding means a password or a passphrase, which generally has a smaller entropy than a random byte sequence. In this case, the passphrase should not be used directly as key, but instead a key derivation function (such as Argon2 or at least PBKDF2) should be applied to derive the *actual* key from the password in conjunction with a random salt for each encryption. The salt is not secret and is given to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext (usually concatenated).
- Regarding the choice of the algorithm: There may be reasons for you to use CCM instead of GCM (legacy applications etc.), but normally (the more modern) GCM is considered superior to CCM and should therefore be applied, see e.g. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/how-to-choose-between-aes-ccm-and-aes-gcm-for-storage-volume-encryption).